# 'delete method of range class failed' in same loop where it also works. Difference is date

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and am writing something that should be able to be done quite easily.  I want to shave down the document to delete rows that meet certain criteria, and then continue to delete rows in this manner.  It works as long as nothing has anything to do with dates.

```
spdate = #11/1/1989#
For i = lastrow To 1 Step -1
If (Sheet.Cells(i, "F").Value = "Apples" Or _
            Sheet.Cells(i, "F").Value = "bananas" Or _
            Sheet.Cells(i, "F").Value = "watermelon" Or _
            Sheet.Cells(i, "F").Value = "mixed fruit" Or _
            Sheet.Cells(i, "F").Value = "basketball" Or _
            Sheet.Cells(i, "F").Value = "") Then
                Sheet.Rows(i).Delete
****ElseIf Sheet.Cells(i, "P").Value > spdate Then
                Sheet.Rows(i).Delete****
ElseIf Sheet.Cells(i, "W").Value = "Other" Then
                Sheet.Rows(i).Delete
End If
Next i
```

That **** area is what is causing all of my problems.  I have tried changing to EntireRow.Delete but I end up with the same error.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: you could also clean up that `If Else Then` block with a nice `Select Case` statement :)

Comment: @Jacob - error is in the title "delete method or range class failed"

Answer (score 0):

Make it `CDate(Sheet.Cells(i, "P").Value)`

You need to cast the string value of a cell into a date when comparing against a date.

EDIT - Please put error message in the original description. Turn off filtering and it will work.

Comment: I did find a horrendously inefficient method of doing this which is to change all of the cells to red, that have the date problem, and then delete all of the red cells.  It's such an inefficient middle man, and especially frustrating that I have to use it.

Comment: You need to convert spdate to a date also. The datatype has to be date. Verify spdate against isDate to see if value is of date datatype. Then apply Datevalue(spdate)

Comment: Your workaround should be fine - however, for your question, the solution is ensuring that you have a proper date datatype to compare against.

Comment: The spdate datatype is of type date.  It's odd.  My code can compare the dates and change the cells to red, but cannot delete them?

Comment: Okay, so if problem is with deleting, just turn off filtering and it should work.

Comment: Is this the proper way to do that? `Sheet.AutoFilterMode = False`

Comment: That should work, however, you need to apply filter after setting filter = False also so that they return since you have it in your excel for a reason. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa199191(v=office.10).aspx        https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa141039(v=office.10).aspx